# How to set and adjust plots with equal axis aspect ratios - CHART.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, axis, aspect-ratio, aspect

I have a project where I show the movements of the robot, I want to make this map so that the x and y scales are proportional to each other.
These data are real-time data, which, as I mentioned, shows the movement of a robot.
Can anyone help me with this?

This is the figure:
[image]

```
myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

type: 'scatter',

data: {

    datasets: [{

        label: '',

        backgroundColor: "blue",
        
        fill: false,

        data: [],

    }]

},

options: {

    scales: {

        xAxes: [{

            ticks:{

                suggestedMax:15,

            }

        }]

        yAxes: [{

            ticks:{

                suggestedMax:15,

            }

        }]

    }

}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the desired dimension of your `canvas` through the [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/width) or [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/height) property.

```
<canvas id="chartContainer" width="400"></canvas>
```

...or using `CSS`.

```
canvas {
  width: 400px;
}
```

Further you should also define `responsive: false` and `aspectRatio: 1` within the chart `options`, latter represents a square canvas.

```
options: {
  responsive: false,
  aspectRatio: 1,
```

> See [Configuration Options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#configuration-options) at the Chart.js documentation